# Java String transform to char array

Tags: java, string

I want to ask how does the `"".value` transform `char array`,Thanks

```
public final class String
implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/**
 * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
 * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
 * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
 */
public String() {
    this.value = "".value;
}
```

Comment: Where did you see this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tell, which JRE implementation you are looking at, when you cite its source code.

However, the code is quite simple:

- `""` refers to a `String` constant which is initialized by the JVM
- since you are inside the `String()` constructor which may get called by application code, but not JVM internal initialization, it may safely refer to the `""` constant
- like any other `String` object, it has the `value` field, so inside the `String` constructor, it is no problem to access that `private` field and copy the reference; it is equivalent to

  ```
  String tmp = "";
  this.value = tmp.value;
  ```

Since both, the `""` constant and the instance created with the `String()` constructor represent empty strings, there is no problem in sharing the `char[]` array instance between them. However, there are reasons against it:

- it is optimizing an uncommon case, as there is usually no reason to ever use the `String()` constructor at all
- it is fragile as it relies on a particular JVM behavior, i.e. that the constant `""` is *not* constructed via the `String()` constructor; if that assumption is wrong, this implementation will create a circular dependency

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
"".value
```

creates empty `char[]` array, equivalent of `this.value = new char[0];`